# Custom Camera Permission config in Unity generated xcode project

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, arkit

I have a Unity project that is kicking out an Xcode project for ARKit. It's a single scene project and uses Vuforia as the camera since I am performing some image recognition for AR - my questions are:

1. Is there a way to show a custom permissions view prior to showing the actual Apple permission? Such as this: https://github.com/IvanVorobei/RequestPermission
2. If Don't allow is hit on the camera permissions alert from Apple, Vuforia seems to its own screen indicating to the user they'll need to navigate to the settings app in order to enable the camera for the app after "Don't Allow" was selected. Is there a way to ditch this screen in place of my own?

   In a normal Xcode project this wouldn't be an issue but I can't seem to locate where this would be done at since I don't see anything related to the Vuforia camera in the project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Vuforia ARCamera it has the `DefaultInitializationErrorHandler` script attached. If you want a custom design for the error handler, copy the `DefaultInitializationErrorHandler` script, rename it and use it instead.